# Showing columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a term x document matrix in pandas (made from a CSV) of the form:

```
cheese, milk, bread, butter
0,2,1,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,1,1
0,1,0,1
```

So if I say '*give me the columns at index 1 and 2 where the values of a given row are both > 0*'.

I want to end up with this:

```
cheese, milk,
[omitted]
1,1
1,1
[omitted]
```

This way, I can sum the `number of rows` / `number of documents` and arrive at a frequent itemset i.e. `(cheese, milk) --[2/4 support]`

I've tried this approach as indicated on a seperate stackoverflow thread:

```
fil_df.select([fil_df.columns[1] > 0 and fil_df.columns[2] > 0], [fil_df.columns[1], fil_df.columns[2]])
```

But it is not working for me sadly. I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Which I don't know how to fix as I can't make my row's cells be `integers` when I make the dataframe from a csv.

Comment: fil_df.columns[1] returns the colomn name not the colomn itself. Hence the TypeError

Comment: Also python is zero-based, so if you want the first two columns you should use 0 and 1 as index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#get 1. and 2. columns
subset = df.iloc[:, [0,1]]
print (subset)
   cheese  milk
0       0     2
1       1     1
2       1     1
3       0     1

#mask
print ((subset > 0))
  cheese  milk
0  False  True
1   True  True
2   True  True
3  False  True

#get all values where True by rows
print ((subset > 0).all(1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

#get first and second columns names
print (df.columns[[0,1]])
Index(['cheese', 'milk'], dtype='object')

print (df.ix[(subset > 0).all(1), df.columns[[0,1]]])
   cheese  milk
1       1     1
2       1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[[1, 2], df.loc[[1, 2]].gt(0).all()]
```

[image]